# Как задать number format для pattern format в Google Visualization?

Tags: javascript, google-api

У меня есть патерн формат для отображения линков на в таблице

```
var options = { allowHtml: true,
cssClassNames: someClass,
width: 10,
height: 10
};

var patterFormat = '<a href="http://somelink/{0}">{0}</a>';
var formatter = new google.visualization.PatternFormat(patterFormat);
formatter.format(tableData, [0, 0]); 

table.draw(tableData, options);
```

На месте {0} будет подставлено чисто порядка 10-тысяч. Возьмем для примера 12345.
По какой причине пару недель назад эта штука перестала нормально работать. Подозреваю что всему виной какой-то апдейт. Теперь на html вместе такой вот линки:

```
<a href="http://somelink/12345">12345</a>
```

зарендерится следующее:

```
<a href="http://somelink/12,345">12,345</a>
```

Появляется сеператор, который мне не нужен. Тип сипоратора зависит от включенной локали в браузере. Я знаю, что я могу воспоьзоваться Number format, но как при этом сохранить формат ссылки? В документации ничего адекватного не нарыл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

все зависело от порядка форматтеров. Number formatter нужно применять до pattern.

```
var numberFormat = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
        pattern: '0'
    });
    numberFormat.format(tableData, 0);

var patterFormat = '<a href="http://somelink/{0}">{0}</a>';
var formatter = new google.visualization.PatternFormat(patterFormat);
formatter.format(tableData, [0, 0]); 

table.draw(tableData, options);
```